# Cannot find interface declaration for 'AFURLSessionManager', superclass of 'AFHTTPSessionManager'?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode5, afnetworking

Recently i have moved my Xcode Project in to `Xcode5.0.2` from the older version of `Xcode 4.6.2`

Now my project working normal in the `4.6.2` but when i exported in `5.0.2` its giving me compilation error `AFURLSessionManager.h`

```
/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h:73:35: Cannot find interface declaration for 'AFURLSessionManager', superclass of 'AFHTTPSessionManager'
```

while there is no issue with `AFHTTPSessionManager` in `Xcode 4.6.2`

I have goggled the thing but cant find any solution. can any one please guide me on this problem??how to solve this.?

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be a bug in the iOS compile-time version checking logic for these classes [referenced in pull request 1486](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1486). I believe this has since been remedied. I'd suggest you retrieve the latest [AFNetworking code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and try again.

Comment: ok i had downloded 2.0 release of AFNetwrking so will it work for IOS >=5 ?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/#requirements), "AFNetworking 2.0 and higher requires Xcode 5, targeting either iOS 6.0 and above, or Mac OS 10.8 Mountain Lion (64-bit with modern Cocoa runtime) and above. For compatibility with iOS 5 or Mac OS X 10.7, use [the latest 1.x release](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/1.x)."

Comment: so if i need to give support for IOS >5.0 then i need to use both the version of AFNetwroking

Comment: @BhavikKama No, I see no reason that you couldn't use 1.x. Clearly, you lose any 2.x features, but that's probably not a big deal.

Comment: can u please tell me how to use two AFnetworking lib for ios 5.0 and ios 6.0 and >

Comment: @BhavikKama As I mentioned above, if you need backward compatibility with iOS 5.x, I'd simply suggest just using [AFNetworking v1.x](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/1.x). It should work fine on iOS 6 and 7, too, but you need AFNetworking 1.x if you want backward compatibility with iOS 5.x.